# Handling with random button with Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I'm trying to use Robot Framework with SeleniumLibrary to click on a random button generator, the HTML was:

```
<div class="btn-number-password noselect">
<p class="btn btn-secondary btn-userpassword" data-keyboard="0">6 or 7</p>
<p class="btn btn-secondary btn-userpassword" data-keyboard="1">2 or 0</p>
<p class="btn btn-secondary btn-userpassword" data-keyboard="2">3 or 8</p>
<p class="btn btn-secondary btn-userpassword" data-keyboard="3">9 or 4</p>
<p class="btn btn-secondary btn-userpassword" data-keyboard="4">5 or 1</p></div>
```

It will generete buttons to a field like:

```
[6 or 7] [2 or 0] [3 or 8] [9 or 4] [5 or 1]
```

These numbers shuffle everytime, so I'm trying to click using text but nothing what I tried works.

Is there any way to click with Robot using text in these buttons?

Comment: You can use logical `and` and `or` in xpath expressions to match for a list of texts.

Comment: use  //*[contains(text(),'6')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chandrashekhar just asked my question, and it worked! Thanks again!

Just to be clear, the answer is:

```
Click Element                      //*[contains(text(),'1')][1]
Click Element                      //*[contains(text(),'4')][1]
Click Element                      //*[contains(text(),'7')][1]
Click Element                      //*[contains(text(),'2')][1]
Click Element                      //*[contains(text(),'5')][1]
Click Element                      //*[contains(text(),'8')][1]
```

You could use a class too to improve your element search:

```
Click Element                      //*[@class='new_window'][1]//*[contains(text(),'1')][1]
```